# Фрагменты андроид

Tags: android-fragment

Использую TabFragment с тремя вложенными фрагментами,при переходе между фрагметами ,они пересоздаются,думаю это неправильно,пж разъясните как организовать все это

public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

```
public static TabLayout tabLayout;
public static ViewPager viewPager;
public static int int_items = 3 ;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /**
     *Inflate tab_layout and setup Views.
     */
        View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));//0,184,99
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(4);

    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.rgb(255,255,255), Color.rgb(255,255,255));




    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(254,196,0));


        viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    /**
     *Set an Apater for the View Pager
     */
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));


    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
               }
    });

    return x;

}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /**
     * Return fragment with respect to Position .
     */

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
      switch (position){//
          case 0 : return new AllOrdersFragment();
          case 1 : return new ListRepetitorsFragment();//ListSubjectFragment();
          case 2 : return new NewsFragment();
      }

    return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return int_items;

    }

    /**
     * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
     */

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0 :
                return "Заявки";
            case 1 :
               return "Ментора";
            case 2 :
                return "Новости";
        }
            return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Приведите код, разметку, статичные ли фрагменты - или динамические(с использованием контейнера)? Без кода помочь Вам невозможно.

Comment: добавил посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: не помогло,все равно спасибо!

Comment: ошибся в коде в одной строчке, сделали поправку.
Попробуйте сейчас.

Comment: Так жее)я ищу наставника по разработке андроид,думаю перешагнул начальный уровень,хочу совершенствоваться,можете скинуть скайп,разумеется буду оплачивать

Comment: Не скажу, что моего уровня хватит, что-бы научить вас чему-то. Такой же самоучка, как и вы.

Comment: может тогда будем сотрудничать,я из Казахстана,есть проекты

Comment: напишите свои контактные данные, скайп или вк.

Comment: ВК: Жуманов Мейрлен, skype: meirlen777

Answer (score 2):

У вас в методе

```
 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
      switch (position){//
          case 0 : return new AllOrdersFragment();
          case 1 : return new ListRepetitorsFragment();//ListSubjectFragment();
          case 2 : return new NewsFragment();
      }
```

каждый раз возвращаются новые инстансы.

Сделайте проверку, нечто вроде этого:

```
AllOrdersFragment orders = new AllOrdersFragment(); // можете инициализировать в поле класса сразу же
// но тогда "ленивой загрузки" не будет.Либо в логически-подходящем куске кода - на ваш выбор.

//сделаем тогда уж геттер
private AllOrdersFragment getOrders() {
    if (orders == null) {
        orders = new AllOrdersFragment();
    }

    return orders;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){//
        case 0 : return getOrders();
        case 1 : return new ListRepetitorsFragment();//ListSubjectFragment();//тут аналогично
        case 2 : return new NewsFragment();//тут аналогично
}
```